# Getting Settings like Username and Password from SQL database

Tags: c#, sql

I have been asked to make a program that gets the Sql database settings of the user.
And if possible, I wanted it to be automated while i'm at it.

I need to get a few values, like the username and password as mentioned in the title. Also, I need to get the db number off a certain database (let's call it rabbit for now).

And to tell the truth... this is where i'm stuck as i have never used SQL.

edit:
a little formulating mistake, i do have knowledge of SQL but i have never used it with a C# combo (in fact all i know is theory of it).

Comment: Do you really want us to teach you databases and SQL? Which version of Visual Studio are you using? An what database system? Maybe there is a very easy way to achieve this... but I'm not sure about the password. Usually you cannot retrieve it in plain text.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, it should be tagged as such.

Comment: Are you having access to the server through username and password? Additionally, the user access should be of root type

Comment: Since you have used SQL: Google `c# database` and read those articles. Come back if you can't get it working and ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some links for start:

C#:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sql_in_csharp.aspx

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/31314-sql-basics-in-c%23/

SQL:

http://www.sqlcourse.com/index.html

http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql.htm

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx?ppud=4

Answer (score 0):

To get to know the basics of SQL I would suggest one of the many tutorials available on the Internet, such as [SQLzoo](http://sqlzoo.net/). Regarding accessing it from C# an article such as [Beginners guide to accessing SQL Server through C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sql_in_csharp.aspx) could be helpful.

Again, there are many more resources regarding both these topics on the Internet.